Reauthenticating when users sign up with OAuth2.0
In my saas app, if a typical user wants to take a sensitive action like setting up 2fa, they need to reauthenticate by entering their password again.
In the case of users who sign up via an oauth provider like Google or Github, what is the best practice for these users to reauthenticate?
Should they:

Be redirected to the oauth provider to reauthenticate?
Confirm an code sent to their email?
Skip re-authentication entirely?
Be forced to create a password before taking these sensitive actions?

I feel like #1 above is somewhat pointless since anyone who has access to their laptop could click to reauthenticate easily. Compared to users who reauthenticate via the normal process of a password, they need to remember it from memory or access their password manager which may be locked so a malicious actor would have more potential difficulty doing this.
What is the best or most common approach? Any real life examples that big companies use? Or what is the standard?

The general concept is that registration should require authentication. But there is no fixed solution since your requirements may vary.
EXAMPLE FLOW

Client runs a code flow
Authorization server (AS) validates parameters and writes a temp cookie to secure authentication screens
AS redirects to the first authentication screen
User selects a Register option and creates an account, providing an email and generated password
AS updates its temp cookie with context and presents a 'please verify your email' screen with a continue button
User has to activate their account using email verification as a form of authentication, then clicks continue
AS verifies that the account is activated and then sets an authentication success result without requiring re-authentication
The client receives an authorization code and can continue as for any other user

GENERAL CONCEPTS

There is a registration authenticator (email verification above) to help prevent spam signups
There is a user authentication method
There is a setup that enables account recovery

ADVANCED EXAMPLE
In Sweden many users have a government approved strong security mobile app called BankID that enables users to present their identity. So you might design a solution with no new passwords like this:

BankID is the registration authenticator
Passkeys is the authentication method since it is quicker and more user friendly than BankID
BankID is also used for account recovery if the user loses their passkey

SUMMARY
The authorization server from the OAuth 2.0 specification should enable you to compose these behaviours according to your particular requirements. Exact details of what is supported will depend on the provider.
